# Does Marketo API support sending emails with dynamic body, subject and recipients?

Tags: c#, rest, api, email, marketo

I've looked into Marketo Email [code samples](https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code) and they're all always refer to either an email created and stored, or at the most, stored with tokens linked to some information related to leads. I have found nothing that satisfy a simple requirement like sending a simple email with dynamic content.

My email sender interface looks like:

```
interface IEmailDelivery
{
  bool Send(IEnumerable<string> recipients, UserNotification notification);
}
```

I'm looking to implement the above interface with Marketo API, where UserNotification contains the content of the email (subject, to address, body, isHtml.. etc)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for this process: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-with-the-marketo-rest-api-part-2-custom-content/  There's currently no direct API to send an email, but this will allow customization of content

Answer (score 2):

Marketo emails are intended to be used as part of a marketing campaign when nurturing customers/prospects.  Marketo, unfortunately for your case, is not the best tool for the job.   SMTP or a cloud based emal solution such as Azure supports or a 3rd party such as mailchimp would be better suited for your request.
But - if you want to use marketo, you can follow the link that the first responder posted (http://developers.marketo.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-with-the-marketo-rest-api-part-1/).